# How to copy a file folder to docker?

Tags: docker

I tried to use the

**docker cp  :**

it always says the

Error: No such container:path:Docker container ID..

Can you tell me how to find the path of the docker(location conatiner) ?

I think the windows file path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using Dockerfile you can use COPY instruction. Else if you want to do it using docker run command, you can do it the following way:

```
docker run -d \
--name devtest \
--mount source=myvol2,target=/app \
nginx:latest
```

or if you want to use docker volume

```
docker run -d \
--name devtest \
-v myvol2:/app \
nginx:latest
```

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

In your case as you want to mount the host directory to container's, it'll be the former

Answer (score 0):

you can copy files/folder in a container using COPY/ADD command in Dockerfile.

```
COPY <host-source> <container-dest>
```

or else you can mount volumes, during docker build or in the docker-compose.yml file.

**Eg. for Dockerfile:**

```
docker run -d \
  --name devtest \
  --mount source=myvol2,target=/app \
  nginx:latest
```

**Eg. for docker-compose.yml file**

```
volumes:
       - db-data:/var/lib/mysql/data
```

Dockerfile: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

docker-compose.yml: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Answer (score 0):

To use docker cp use the instruction as shown:

```
docker cp ./path/to/local/folder/. ContainerName:/app/
```

You have to provide the container id/name for container name.

```
docker ps --filter status=running
```

The above command will show you the running containers, from where you can select the target container name or id for use (first about 4 characters of the id should be enough)